# Реализация сортировки подсчетом

Tags: java, сортировка

Могу реализовать разные сортировки, но с **сортировкой подсчетом** встречаюсь впервые.

Как реализовать этот алгоритм?Не получается запустить счетчик

```
int nums[] = {1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1};
int a[] = new int[10];
int count[] = new int[4];
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    count[i] = 0;
}

for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

    count[nums[j]] = count[nums[j]] + 1;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Сортировка подсчетом подразумевает создание корзин (buckets), в каждой из которых хранится количество элементов исходного массива, значение которых совпадает с индексом корзины. Соответственно, нужно иметь корзины, индексы которых будут от минимального значения массива до максимального.

При использовании массива для хранения корзин индексы будут от `0` до `X`. Чтобы при этом можно было работать с отрицательными числами, а также чтобы не хранить ненужные значения от `0` до минимального значения из массива, имеет смысл перед сортировкой (или непосредственно перед добавлением в корзину) вычесть из всех элементов массива минимум, а после сортировки (при извлечении из корзины) - добавить его обратно.

В итоге получается так:

```
public static void sort(int[] array)
{
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int element : array)
    {
        if (element < min)
        {
            min = element;
        }
        if (element > max)
        {
            max = element;
        }
    }
    int[] buckets = new int[max - min + 1];
    for (int element : array)
    {
        buckets[element - min]++;
    }
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = buckets[i]; j > 0; j--)
        {
            array[arrayIndex++] = i + min;
        }
    }
}
```